# How can you get a Linux top like output using C

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to get the CPU usage and details of all the running processes on embedded Linux while a C test is running. Is there a `top` equivalent in C that I could use ?

Comment: You can't just run `top` over a serial console?

Comment: What do you suppose `top` is written in?!

Comment: Let me clarify. C test in running on the device. And I want to get `top` like information from within my C code. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `top`, you should probably use `ps` with the right arguments and you can parse the output.

You'll have to call that with a `system` call or `popen` from your C code. You cannot get this information strictly inside your C code (at least I don't think you can).

Comment: I used system("top -b -n 1 > topout"); and it dumped the output of top to topout. This worked, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what aspect of `top` confuses you, but just take a look at the [source code for top](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/top.c?view=markup).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to parse the /proc file system. The kernel has a special file system which is normally mounted at /proc with a unique directory for each process (eg. /proc/30 belongs to the process with PID=30). The files in these directories are all text files and contains lots of info on the running processes.